# update bash variable everytime it is called

Tags: bash, variables

In my .bashrc I'm setting a bash variable to the output of a script

```
export FOO=`/home/jist/tools/lookup1.pl`
```

This works great except that the output of that script can change during the day (mainly depending on if I'm on the company's VPN or not).  So when I do something with the variable, I want it to re-execute the script and get the updated value.  I have no idea how to do this?  Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create a cronjob that calls it every X minutes.

Comment: A cronjob isn't ideal since the value might change and the variable might be used before the job is run.

Comment: Make it a function emitting a refreshed value on stdout instead of a variable and always access it as `$(FOO)`?

Comment: Never knew you could do functions with bash.  Thanks! That really seems to be the easiest.

Comment: @fedorqui: A cron job wouldn't work at all; it runs outside your `bash` shell process, so it can't update shell or environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

As described in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974695/update-bash-variable-everytime-it-is-called#comment22773812_15974695) by [William](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2005672/william):

> Make it a function emitting a refreshed value on stdout instead of a variable and always access it as `$(FOO)`

That means:

```
# create the function: put this in your .bashrc
FOO() { /home/jist/tools/lookup1.pl "$@"; }

# use the function and store its output: do this whenever you want the current result
currentFooResult=$(FOO)

# or, to just print the result to stdout:
FOO
```